# couldn't nullify associated child object in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, associations, destroy

I have a class `Trainer` associated with many `Facilities` and many `ServiceClasses`. I just want to make reference `null` in facilities and `service_classes` table when trainer record is destroyed.

Whenever I try `trainer.destroy`, it shows me errors as I mention in the screenshot.
I also tried callbacks to make reference `null` `before_destroy` but it didn't work for me either.

Thanks in advance if someone can guide me, it has already taken me a lot of time.

Trainer:

```
 class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :service_classes,dependent: :nullify
   has_many :facilities,dependent: :nullify
 end
```

Service Class:

```
class ServiceClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  mount_uploader :image, EventUploader
  belongs_to :trainer
end
```

Facility Class:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :facility_category
  has_many :facility_prices
    has_many :facility_details
  belongs_to :trainer
end
```

Schema:

```
   create_table "service_classes", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.text     "description"
        t.string   "image"
        t.integer  "user_id"
        t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
        t.datetime "deleted_at"
        t.integer  "trainer_id"
      end

      add_index "service_classes", ["deleted_at"], name: "index_service_classes_on_deleted_at", using: :btree
      add_index "service_classes", ["trainer_id"], name: "index_service_classes_on_trainer_id", using: :btree


 create_table "facilities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "facility_category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.integer  "trainer_id"
  end

  add_index "facilities", ["deleted_at"], name: "index_facilities_on_deleted_at", using: :btree
  add_index "facilities", ["trainer_id"], name: "index_facilities_on_trainer_id", using: :btree
```

[image: couldn't destroy object]

Comment: did you try `allow_nil: true` option?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon   I tried but got errors:


ArgumentError: Unknown key: :allow_nil. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type

Comment: why do you `nullify` though? As i can see, u have paranoia gem, `dependent: :destroy` doesn't serve properly?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon when I remove nullify , it doesn't run any sql for update null foreign key and  getting same error.
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "trainers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_b166f6b7eb" on table "service_classes"

Comment: try `validate: false` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Same Error:
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "trainers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_b166f6b7eb" on table "service_classes"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "service_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143475/discussion-between-thevinspro-and-md-farhan-memon).

Comment: did you try `dependent: :destroy` and not just remove `nullify`?

Comment: i mean to replace `nullify` with `destroy`/`delete` as delete doesn't run callbacks, that should work mostly. and if not, try `dependent: :destroy` after removing `acts_as_paranoid` from model. There must be a conflict.